# Ordenar un f:selectItems Alfabéticamente, JAVA, JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

tengo un f:selectItems y no se cómo puedo ordenarlo, llevo 1 día dándole vueltas y no lo consigo.

Aquí muestro el código:

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu onchange="PF('widgetAuditDTO').filter()" multiple="true"
    filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith"
    label="Operacion"  style="width:300px" scrollHeight="150" 
    value="#{auditBean.selectedOperations}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{auditBean.sourceOpera}" style="width: 15%"
        var="operations" itemLabel="#{opera.desc}" itemValue="#{opera.desc}" />
<p:ajax event="change" process="@this" />
```

Por todo lo que he buscado, una simple etiqueta que lo ordene creo que no existe ya que es una llamada a base de datos.

Comment: ¿Algún motivo por el que no ordenas los valores en el bean (sourceOpera)?

Comment: Cómo podría hacerlo? mas o menos me hago una idea, pero recibiendo los valores de bbdd nunca lo he hecho @JaviMollá

Comment: Igual que ordenas listas en cualquier otro código java, o (viniendo de bbdd) en SQL. Si eso te causa problemas, te recomiendo que te tomes algo de trabajo para familiarizarte con Java SE antes de meterte en tecnologías complicadas como JSF y Java EE en general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordena la lista en el bean (java). En el método donde obtienes la lista:

```
Collections.sort(sourceOpera, new Comparator<Opera>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Opera o1, Opera o2) {
        return o1.getDesc().compareTo(o2.getDesc());
    }
});
```

Comment: Gracias tío, me funcionó perfecto